# Dynamic Data in Android

Tags: php, android, database

I am displaying a value from my database field.
when I change the value from database, I need to restart the activity to see the new value.

Now, I am looking for a block of code that will continuously check for the new value.

Thanks.

> Blockquote
>   This is my first post. so sorry about the title or language I used.
>   Blockquote

Comment: "Now, I am looking for a block of code". This is not what Stack Overflow is for

Comment: No problem with ur language or title, problem is that u r asking us to write code for u.here u can ask something to know or correct ur code.

Comment: Who prevents you from reading the database field from Activity without restarting your application? Or do you have no source code for that Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well no one will write a block of code for you. But yes suggestion is you can do this using thread and or AsyncTask. and As per my knowledge AsyncTask is the best option. Here is some tutorial which may help you..

1.[this is best tutorial for AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

2.[official android dev. link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

3.[This is also nice](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html)

Best Luck